# Ajax jQuery Change Submit Input Button Value - But lose CSS Formatting

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Using jQuery to change the text of a submit input button when pressed on an Ajax request. The text changes as required but I lose all of the CSS text formatting and the html submit button markup.

html:

```
<div class="submit-control">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
<div class="counter">
<span id="total"><b>0</b></span> Entered
<span id="remain"><b>2000</b></span> Remaining
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.submit-control input {

  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Times, Serif;
  float:left;

}

.counter {
  color: #606060;
  border: 2px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Times, Serif;

}

.counter  span {
margin-left: 10px;
color: #FFD700;

}

#total  {
  color: #606060;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#remain  {
  color: #606060;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        var msg=$("#msg").val();
        var userId = "<?php echo session_id();?>";
        $.ajax({
            url:'../serverside/insert.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                msg:msg,
                userId:userId
            },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#submit').html("Processing...");
    },
    success: function(response){
        $('#submit').html(response);
    }
        });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I won't this formatting. Picture before I press the button:

[image]

But I'm getting the below (as losing all the css as the html is cleared under the 'submit-control' class):

[image]

EDIT:

Elements in Google Chrome before pressing button:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: can u create jsfiddle please

Comment: @Çağrı sorry tried to replicate the code in jsfiddle but couldn't make an example work. I've added some info above (CSS plus html before and after pressing submit). Does that help. I know its not perfect. Thank you.

Comment: code u shared doesn't have any problem. But in picture your content goes . there must be a reason for this so u should share your all js code for this page to understand problem. this code doesn't clear content.

Answer (score 0):

Try `val` instead of `html` :

```
$('#submit').val("Processing...");

$('#submit').val(response);
```

Comment: Thank you. Tried the above. But the same thing is still happening.